# slideDown/Up not work properly

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

in the past days I switched my menu to mobile friendly version. Is nearly done so far, only one issue remains: I use jQuery slideUp and slideDown to make the submenus (in)visible. Unfortunately these don't work properly: The sliding is not smooth as it should be but very rapid. Using slideToggle instead didn't make things better. On the other hand the menu button that makes the complete menu visible slides fine; I'm using slideToggle here.
My JS code:

```
$("#Navigation li.submenu").click(function () {
    if ($("#menu02 div#menu-icon").css("display") == "block") {
        if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).children("ul").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).css("background-position", "right -100px")
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("open");
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown("slow");
            $(this).css("background-position", "right -170px")
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

My test page:
http://ulrichbangert.de/indexr3.php
(Resize the viewport to a small width until the menu has one column.)
Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: Seems smooth on my machine.
You have alot of animation running on your site which moved with the animation, this makes the animation very heavy to render.

Answer (score 0):

The animation is smooth on my machine.
I think the problem is that you have allot of animations on your site, which makes it heavy to render.
When you animate the menu you slide the entire site down, which forces a reflow(recalculation and rerendering) in every animation step.
Try setting the menu as absolute, so it slides in front of the site instead, therefor not forcing a reflow of the entire site.
Alternatively you can try pausing some of your other animations while sliding the menu down.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There seems to be some misunderstanding. To clarify things I've made a screenshot: http://ulrichbangert.de/div/menu.png The button on the upper right (marked with a blue arrow) slides down the complete menu. This one slides the complete page and is fine for me too. But there are some additional + buttons (marked with red arrows) that slide down the submenus. These do not slide down the complete page and are those where my problem occurs.

Comment: Now I was able to solve this problem on my own: The ul also had a CSS animation for the height which I need for the desktop version. Obviously both animations, CSS and jQuery, interfered and caused this unwanted effect. Now I used Mediaquery and activated the CSS animation only for the desktop version. Now the sliding down is as smooth as it shoud be.